# How to change path of cabal config file?

Tags: windows, haskell, path, cabal, haskell-platform

I am using HaskellPlatform-2012.4.0.0 on Win7. It's installed as portable. Paths are managed through .bat file so `ghci` and `ghc` works.
But cabal installs it self at C:\Users\name\AppData\Roaming\cabal\
To circumvent that I did:

```
cabal update
edit config file
delete all files except config
```

Changed paths:

```
remote-repo-cache: d:\h1\cabal\packages 
world-file: d:\h1\cabal\world
build-summary: d:\h1\cabal\logs\build.log
```

It works, but it's far from truly portable.

Cabal config is bigger problem. It seems that it must be left in C:\Users\name\AppData\Roaming\cabal which is not portable at all.
First run of `cabal update` says `Config file path source is default config file.`

Questions:
1. where is that default config file?
2. can remote-repo-cache, world-file and other paths be relative?
3. is there a way of setting default cabal path so it never goes to C:\Users\name\AppData\Roaming\cabal

Comment: Looks like it can be set with the `CABAL_CONFIG` env variable, see: https://github.com/haskell/cabal/commit/1dc46087064845ab4942687e79f182e28e89332c

Comment: To my surprise `SET CABAL_CONFIG=%~dp0cabal\bin\config` works :) It's important to say that **config** is file name. Paths inside config file are still wrong, but that could be fixed by implanting config file before cabal starts for the first time.

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but it seems that paths in config need to be absolute. Relative paths create `Haskell\cabal` folders in current dir where you started cabal install xxx :D Absolute path `\Haskell\cabal` is ok for `cabal update`, but doesn't work for `cabal install xxx` Only pure absolute path `D:\Haskell\cabal` works.    p.s. put your comment as an answer. it covers questions 1&3. So far it seems that nothing could be done about q2.

Comment: @Nathan Howell: Anytime now would be good ;)

Answer (score 4):

Run cabal with:

```
cabal --config-file="path/to/config"
```

Comment: That gives `cabal: no command given (try --help)` or  `cabal: unrecognized option '--config-file=d:\h1\cabal\bin\config'`

Comment: You cert.ainly need to provide a command :)  What version of cabal-install do you have?

Comment: `cabal-install version 0.14.0` it can not be updated through cabal install cabal-install. what command? `cabal update` or `cabal install` with that switch says `cabal: unrecognized option '--config-file=d:\cfg'`

Comment: @CoR I have the same version, you have to put the switch *before* any command.  Like `cabal --config-file=... install ...`

Comment: `cabal --config-file="D:\HaskellStack\cabal\config" update`