# How to change path of ghc?

Tags: windows, haskell, path, ghc, haskell-platform

I'm using HaskellPlatform-2012.4.0.0 on Win7. It's installed as portable. Paths are managed through .bat file so ghci and ghc works. Cabal config and folder are made semi-portable with [this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14368401/how-to-change-path-of-cabal-config-file)

The problem is `ghc` folder. It installs itself in `C:\Users\name\AppData\Roaming\ghc\i386-mingw32-7.4.1.`

How to change it's default path? So I can have really portable Haskell on windows :)

EDIT:
There are 3 new system variables that do nothing. Here are results:

```
SET APPDATA=%~dp0AppData   -- has no effect. ghc is still made in roaming
SET USERPROFILE=%~dp0  -- kills cabal
SET LOCALAPPDATA=%~dp0Local   --not sure if this is ever used.
```

[kills cabal error link](https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/700)

Comment: I think its the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14368401/how-to-change-path-of-cabal-config-file

Comment: Not the same, he mentioned that one in his question.

Comment: Well, yes. That's my question too ;)

Comment: What is the `$APPDATA/ghc` directory storing? I see a the ghci history, but what's the architecture specific folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try `SET USERPROFILE=%~dp0` while making sure that the folder structure supports what Cabal expects. It is probably attempting to go to `%USERPROFILE%AppData\Roaming` or something similar.

Comment: Yup, that worked. It's an ugly hack, but it worked. I tried 10 different combinations, but missed that GHC/mingw may have hard coded paths.

Answer (score 0):

You can use symbolic links `mklink /D linkName target` /D means directory symlink. This command available since Windows Vista/2008+

```
cd C:\Users\myself\AppData\Roaming
mklink /D cabal C:\installed\cabal
mklink /D ghc C:\installed\ghc
```

More info on symlinks http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_symbolic_link